# beamer's \only causes shifts

Tags: beamer

When using `\only` with LaTeXs `beamer` package, distances seem to change:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{}
\begin{columns}[T]
    \fbox{%
    \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
        Test
        \only<-4>{\[a\]}
        \only<5>{\[b\]}
        \only<6>{\[c\]}
        \only<7>{\[d\]}
        \only<4->{\fbox{\textbf{Test}}}
        \only<5->{%
            \begin{itemize}
                \item b
                \only<6->{\item c}
                \only<7->{\item d}
            \end{itemize}}
    \end{column}}
    \fbox{%
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{column}}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The second Test slides along from frame to frame (all slides overlayed):

[image]

What is happening here?

(**P.S.** And why are the columns not centered?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- the `Test` box moves because each line ending acts like a space. To avoid this, you can protect the line endings with a `%` sign
- Beamer does not like other content in the `columns` environment other than columns. You can make the columns centred by moving the `\fbox` inside the columns:

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{}
\begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
            Test
        \only<-4>{\[a\]}%
        \only<5>{\[b\]}%
        \only<6>{\[c\]}%
        \only<7>{\[d\]}%
        \only<4->{\fbox{\textbf{Test}}}%
        \only<5->{%
            \begin{itemize}
                \item b
                \only<6->{\item c}
                \only<7->{\item d}
            \end{itemize}}%
                \end{minipage}}%
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
            \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule]{example-image-a}}%
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Suuuehgi You're welcome!